# Expressing simple geometry manipulation computational graph

Tags: compiler-construction, dsl

I'm writing a simple geometry composition/manipulation library. The library needs to allow the clients to express high-level logic like below:

```
table_base = Cylinder(r=..., h=..., anchor=None)
table_stem = Cylinder(r=..., h=..., anchor=None)
table_top = Cylinder(r=..., h=..., anchor=None)

# Build an abstract entity 'table' by specifying relationships
# between its components. No concrete locations specified yet. 
table = Geometry()
table.add(table_base)
table.stack(table_stem, table_base)
table.stack(table_top, table_stem)

# Provide concrete location for the base
# Assume 'table_base' is accessible via its name
table['table_base'].anchor = (0, 0, 0)  

# At this point we have information to populate 
# 'anchor' locations for other components
table.build()
```

As shown above, we first build primitives (assume I have representations for that). Then we build `table` as an abstract geometry object. Finally we provide the anchor location for the base. When I hit `build()`, I want this information to cascade down the dependency tree and populate `anchor` locations for other components. Admittedly, I can require clients to bookeep their own anchor locations, but with complex objects it becomes tedious. What is an appropriate representation to hold the abstract relationships between the components prior to the `build` step?

As you can probably tell, I dont have background in compilers or writing DSLs. So even the name for what I'm looking for would be a great starting point. Language preference Python, but I'm more interested in conceptual understanding.

Comment: Except for the ellipses, which I assume are place holders, this all looks like valid Python code to me, so I'm not sure why you want to write your own compiler for this. Can't you just write this as a Python library?

Comment: Yes, its valid python code. Also I want to avoid writing my own compiler obviously. The only gap is that I want a data structure to hold the symbolic relationships. E.g. when I call `stack()` I want to express that `top.anchor.z = bottom.anchor.z + bottom.height`. But the actual data for computing anchors and locations is not available until much later. What is a right data structure for holding such symbolic relationships?